# Why does `using A::f` not work as expected?

Tags: c++, namespaces, using

The following code is rejected by VC++ and clang.

Why does `using A::f` not work as expected?

Is there any way to hide some names in a given name space?

```
namespace A
{
    int f()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

namespace B
{
    int f()
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

using namespace A;
using namespace B;

using A::f; // I want to hide B::f and only use A::f, how to do?

int main()
{
    auto n = f(); // error : call to 'f' is ambiguous
}
```

Comment: Can you come up with a title that won't require future visitors to name their namespaces and variables the same way you did to find it?

Comment: Why do you expect it to work? Both the `f()`s are visible. Also, you don't need a semicolon after the closing brace of a namespace.

Comment: The using declaration is purely redundant here.

Comment: C++ `using` is not Java `import`. In java you can do something like `import java.util.*; import java.sql.*; import java.sql.Date;` and clear up the ambiguity. In C++ you can't.

Answer (score 4):

The standard specifies the interpretation of the `using` directive. Emphasis mine:

> A *using-directive* specifies that the names in the nominated namespace can be used in the scope in which the
>    *using-directive* appears after the *using-directive*. **During unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), the names appear
>     as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the *using-directive* and the
>    nominated namespace.** [ *Note:* In this context, “contains” means “contains directly or indirectly”. — end
>             note ]

(C++11 §7.3.4/2)

Thus, after

```
using namespace A;
using namespace B;
```

an unqualified lookup for the name `f` finds `A::f` and `B::f` *as though they have been declared in the global namespace*. The declaration `using A::f` introduces the name `f` into the global namespace in the same way (although it differs in that it actually makes `A::f` a member of the global namespace), so it is redundant as far as unqualified lookup goes. The point is that unqualified name lookup for `f` finds both `A::f` and `B::f` in the same declarative region.

**Solution?**

```
int main()
{
    using A::f;
    auto n = f(); // no longer ambiguous; finds A::f
}
```

The first place that unqualified name lookup looks in is the block scope of `main`, so it will find only `A::f`, even though `A::f` and `B::f` would both be found in the enclosing namespace scope if searched.

Answer (score 2):

Because of this:

```
using namespace A;
using namespace B;
```

Both `f` functions are in scope.  They have the same signature, so what would you expect to happen?

This using directive:

```
using A::f();
```

Is redundant.

Comment: obviously the OP was confused because they magically expected the redundant directive to override `using namespace B`.

Comment: @djechlin: Ok, well that's wrong and I said so.  What's your point?  Do you just not like how I worded it? It's true that I didn't go to the spec.

Comment: Firstly I wrote the comment before your edit. But your exact words were "what would you expect to happen?" which I feel was obvious from the question, and obvious in such a way that makes it clear that using both namespaces really wasn't the point (so it was actually a strictly correct but useless answer before your edit). The OP wanted to know why the redundant using didn't do anything, to which a perfectly good answer is "it just doesn't" (which is explained in your edit).

Comment: I don't think quoting the spec is necessary. Probably the OP had a more complicated problem based on this misunderstanding, narrowed it down to that example, and is surprised enough it was worth confirming on SO or somewhere authoritative. To the OP the behavior could have plausibly been more subtle than "it's redundant." Maybe it was "you have to put the using A::f first to avoid conflicts later." Or some other subtlety.